# Video hides for a second when playing in safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm playing some videos on mouseenter, and everything is working right on Chrome but not in Safari, here's an example of what happens: (Gif: https://gyazo.com/cc4693840cd30fee3f61cda6082e6f7f)

Also tried to play the video with 'canplay' event...
[Canplay](https://gyazo.com/ad11f4c505e6be8d5606ac1eb2f72876)

It hides itself just before playing the video... It should not jump, right after remove the poster the video should play... I've tried also with preload="auto" and loading the video first in js and after a few seconds playing it with a settimeout

It only happens the first time you hover the video (because it has to load)

First time it happens to me

Here's the code:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.work').forEach((work) => {
  work.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    // this.querySelector('video').load();
    // setTimeout(() => {
      this.querySelector('video').play();
    // }, 3000);
  })
  work.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    this.querySelector('video').currentTime = 0;
    this.querySelector('video').pause();
  });
});
```

```css
.work {
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
}
.work:before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
    
video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  right: 0;
  left: 0; 
}
```

```html
<div class="work"><video muted="" playsinline="" preload="metadata" loop="" src="https://player.vimeo.com/progressive_redirect/playback/670660302/rendition/1080p/1080p.mp4?loc=external&signature=23ceaaa3a5475f94cfbe326a81c9c01ce8b02a217e54c7262bb6cf23dd3390d3" poster="http://ticklefilm.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/IMG_9660-720x1080.jpg"></video></div>
```